# server-side fallback rendering

Tags: three.js

Is there any way to have three.js running server-side on a headless server (standalone server, Amazon AWS or similar)?

Currently I fall back to canvas rendering (wireframe only for performance reasons) when user's browser does not support WebGL. This is good enough for realtime interaction, but for the app to make sense, users would really need to somehow be able to see a properly rendered version with lights, shadows, post processing etc. even if it comes with great latency.

So... would it be possible to create a server-side service with functional three.js instance? The client would still use tree.js canvas wireframe rendering, but after say... a second of inactivity, it would request via AJAX a full render from the server-side service, and overlay it simply as an image.

Are there currently any applications, libraries or anything that would allow such a thing (functional javascript+webgl+three.js on a headless, preferably linux server, and GPU-less at that)?

PhantomJS comes to mind, but apparently it does not yet support WebGL: http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=273

Or any alternative approaches to the problem? Going the route of programmatically controlling a full desktop machine with a GPU and standard chrome/firefox instance feels possible, while fragile, and I really really wouldn't want to go there if there are any software-only solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In its QA infrastructure, Google can run Chromium testing using Mesa (see issue [97675](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=97675), via the switch `--use-gl=osmesa`). The software rasterizer in the latest edition of Mesa is pretty advanced, involving the use of LLVM to convert the shaders and emulate the execution on the CPU. Your first adventure could be building Mesa, building Chromium, and then try to tie them together.

As a side note, this is also what I plan (in the near future) for PhantomJS itself, in particular since Qt is also moving in that direction, i.e. using Mesa/LLVMpipe instead of its own raster engine only. [The numbers](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/05/31/qml-scene-graph-in-master/) actually look good. Even better, for an offline, non-animated single-shot capture, the performance would be more than satisfactory.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for (well, in the absence of more readily available options). I was not aware of Chromium support for Mesa renderer.. hopefully I'll have success with that, or even better if you get it working in PhantomJS first :)

Comment: @yaku were you able to run Chromium with Mesa renderer?

Comment: @frank No I didn't. Not to say it couldn't be done, just that I don't have much experience building and tweaking huge pieces of software. Still looking forward to try it again sometime, or if PhantomJS or other existing solutions get to support WebGL.

Comment: This may have been added since this comment thread (4 years ago) but PhantomJS have categorically declared that they do not intend to support WebGL http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html#unsupported-features

Answer (score 1):

Some inputs in this thread : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2182

In particular this [demo](http://www.screenr.com/8648) shows how to generate some images on server side using nodejs.

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it's CanvasRenderer only. I'm looking for full WebGLRenderer capabilities, even if they were non-accelerated and rendered in software (around 1 FPS should be enough for this purpose). Somehow making node.js (or phantomjs) to work with a software OpenGL renderer like osmesa or llvmpipe (?) might be the way to go, but that is.. I don't know where to start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Links below will not resolve your problem with AWS but will give you a hint.

I am working on the application with a similar architecture and came across with these examples:

[Multiplayer game with realtime socket.io](https://github.com/dirkk0/multiplay)

[My original question on similar architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719666/run-three-js-on-server-with-a-help-of-node-js-export-model-to-json-and-load-to)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.