# run three.js on server with a help of node.js, export model to json and load to end user through ajax

Tags: json, node.js, three.js, mesh, sample

I have a JavaScript app with a requirement to protect the drawing interface of the model so that it is not to public.

I want to use three.js on a server, save the model in JSON format and deliver it the client side. Three.js on the client will display it. But I don't know how to implement it on a server.

Are there any Node.js examples that run three.js apps? If so, how do I save a mesh into JSON format from three.js?

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't know how to implement it on a server.

[three module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/three)

> Are there any Node.js examples that run three.js apps?

[Yes](https://www.npmjs.org/package/threeflow#usage)

> If so, how do I save a mesh into JSON format from three.js?

[three-obj module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/three-obj)